# When first add recycler view item, it will not delete on the first delete button, but when recheck it after delete press, it will delete, why?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have an app where alarm items are added to my recycler view. They are added to a list and added to a room database. The recycler view updates from the list. When I first add say 3 alarms to the view, then I click on the delete checkbox, and then hit the delete button, it will not work. The view will reset, and then I click the delete checkbox again, and then click delete, it will delete from the recycler view then. Also if say I add some alarms, and then close the app, and reopen it, it will work on the first delete. So, basically, when I first add recyclerview items, they will not update/delete properly until I hit the delete button and recheck them, or I restart the app. They are deleted via boolean in a sql table, they are not updating in the sql database when they are first added like they are supposed to. Also how do I break these files into sepereate ones below.

```
private lateinit var alarmList: MutableList<Alarm>
private lateinit var deleteAlarmList: MutableList<Alarm>
private lateinit var addAlarmButton: Button
private lateinit var deleteAlarmButton: Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



//private var rvAlarms = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.alarmListRecyclerView)
private lateinit var rvAlarms: RecyclerView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    rvAlarms = findViewById(R.id.alarmListRecyclerView)
    addAlarmButton = findViewById(R.id.addAlarmButton)
    deleteAlarmButton = findViewById(R.id.deleteAlarmButton)

    AlarmRepository.initialize(this)
    val alarmRepository = AlarmRepository.get()






    val alarm5 = Alarm()
   // val alarm6 = Alarm()
   // val alarm7 = Alarm()
    var list: MutableList<Alarm> = mutableListOf()
    deleteAlarmList = list
    alarmList = alarmRepository.getAlarmList() as MutableList<Alarm>
    //list.add(alarm6)
    rvSet()


    //add alarm button listener
    //adds new alarm on click
    addAlarmButton.setOnClickListener {
        val alarm = Alarm()
        alarmList.add(alarm)
        rvSet()
        alarmRepository.addAlarm(alarm)

    }


    //delete alarm button listener
    //deletes all alarms checked with delete mark
    deleteAlarmButton.setOnClickListener {
    /*    var listIterator = alarmRepository.getAlarmList()
        val itr = listIterator.iterator()
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            var alar = itr.next()
            if (alar.deleteCheck){

*/
        alarmRepository.deleteAlarms()//fixme possible background thread done after next line 
here
        alarmList = alarmRepository.getAlarmList() as MutableList<Alarm>
        rvSet()

            }

        }



fun rvSet () {
    var alarmAdapter = AlarmAdapter(alarmList)
    rvAlarms.adapter = alarmAdapter
    rvAlarms.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

}

}
```

////////////////////

```
class AlarmAdapter(private val alarmList: List<Alarm>) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmAdapter.AlarmViewHolder>() {


val alarmRepository = AlarmRepository.get()


class AlarmViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val alarmRepository = AlarmRepository.get()

    val mondayCheckBox: CheckBox
    val deleteCheckBox: CheckBox
    val alarmLabel: TextView
    init {
        mondayCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.mondayCheckBox)
        deleteCheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteAlarmCheckBox)
        alarmLabel = view.findViewById(R.id.alarmLabel)

        mondayCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
            alarmLabel.text = "success"
        }

    }

}




override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AlarmViewHolder {


    return AlarmViewHolder(

        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, parent, false)
    )
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AlarmViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val alarm = alarmList[position]

   holder.itemView.apply {
       deleteAlarmCheckBox.setOnClickListener {
           alarm.deleteCheck = !alarm.deleteCheck
           alarmRepository.updateAlarm(alarm)

       }
   }
}




override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return  alarmList.size
}





}
```

//////////

```
@Database(entities = [Alarm::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AlarmDataBase : RoomDatabase() {

//abstract val alarmDataBaseDao: AlarmDatabaseDao
abstract fun alarmDao(): AlarmDatabaseDao


}
```

////////////

```
@Dao
interface AlarmDatabaseDao {


@Insert
fun insertAlarm(alarm: Alarm)

@Update
fun updateAlarm(alarm: Alarm)

@Query("SELECT * FROM alarm_database2 ORDER BY hour ASC")
fun getAllAlarms(): List<Alarm>

@Query("DELETE FROM alarm_database2 WHERE deleteCheck = 1")
fun deleteAlarms(): Integer


@Delete
fun deleteAlarm(alarm: Alarm)

}
```

//////////

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.alarmapp2.Alarm
import com.example.alarmapp2.MainActivity
import java.util.concurrent.Executors


class AlarmRepository private constructor(context: Context) {


val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context.applicationContext,
    AlarmDataBase::class.java, "alarm_database2"
).allowMainThreadQueries().build()

private val alarmDao  = db.alarmDao()
private val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()


fun getAlarmList(): List<Alarm> = alarmDao.getAllAlarms()

//fun getCrime(id: UUID): LiveData<Alarm?> = alarmDao.ge(id)


fun addAlarm(alarm: Alarm) {

        alarmDao.insertAlarm(alarm)

}

fun deleteAlarms() {
    //executor.execute {
        alarmDao.deleteAlarms()
        

    //}

}

fun updateAlarm(alarm: Alarm) {

        alarmDao.updateAlarm(alarm)

}


companion object {
    private var INSTANCE: AlarmRepository? = null

    fun initialize(context: MainActivity) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = AlarmRepository(context)
        }
    }

    fun get(): AlarmRepository {
        return INSTANCE
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("AlarmRepository must be initialized")
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to call `notifyItemRemoved(position)` or `notifyDataSetChanged()` when item removed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for the response. I made it work somehow. You can check my answer if curious.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out. I had to refresh my list with the alarm objects currently in the database. I dont know why exactly. But it works. Here is what i added to the add alarm button.

```
 addAlarmButton.setOnClickListener {
        val alarm = Alarm()
        alarmRepository.addAlarm(alarm)
        alarmList = alarmRepository.getAlarmList() as MutableList<Alarm>
        rvSet()
    }
```